# Boostrap 3, IE8 and mobile display

Tags: mobile, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've read the following from the bootstrap doc:

> > You'll still need Respond.js for IE8 (since our media queries are still there and need to be processed). This disables the "mobile site" aspects of Bootstrap.

Is there a way around this?  More specifically, is there a way to have a website using bootstrap 3 display like it should on IE8 and mobile devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quote you included is actually from the section describing how to **purposefully turn off the responsiveness** of the site (turn off mobile support).

`Respond.js` actually makes your site responsive on IE8, and will have no effect on other browser.

Use a conditional statement, and `respond.js` will only load for IE8.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks Schmalzy.  By conditionally including html5shiv.js, respond.js, and including the "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">" tag did the trick.